# Update de una tabla comparando o calculando con otra

Tags: sql, oracle

Necesito hacer un Update de una tabla comparando o calculando con otra.

Tengo una tabla de **`jugadores`** con todos sus datos incluye `sueldo`, `rut`, y otros campos. Además, tengo la tabla **`partidos`** con su respectivo `id` por cada partido y el `rut` de cada jugador. Entonces, a cada jugador que ha jugado más de 50 partidos (puede ser 10, 20 o cualquier otro número) se le asigna el doble del sueldo en la tabla jugador (puede ser un porcentaje más), pero depende de la cantidad de partidos jugados.

Por eso, en lo que intenté hasta ahora, cuento los `id` de partidos cuando el `rut` es igual (o puede ser otro campo).

Generalizando lo que intenté:

```
Update jugadores
Set sueldo = sueldo*2
Join partidos
on(jugdores.rut=partidos.rut)
Having count(partidos.id)>50;
```

...pero me salen errores `ora-00933`.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: no entiendo en este query: para que esta el join. como tener un having sin un group by.. el error que te esta dando es que el query no esta bien formulado

Comment: Muy agradecido por sus respuestas, me sirvieron mucho y logre terminar el codigo. mil gracias

Answer (score 3):

Según lo que te he entendido, lo que necesitas es lo siguiente:

```
UPDATE T1 SET T1.C1 = T1.C1*3 WHERE T1.C2 = (SELECT T2.C2 FROM T2 WHERE T1.C2 = T2.C2)
```

Por supuesto, faltaría la condición del having, pero con lo que has escrito no comprendo el objetivo ni cual sería la condición de agrupación.

**EDIT:
Tras tu respuesta, esto debería valerte:**

```
UPDATE JUGADORES J 
SET J.SALARIO = J.SALARIO*2 
WHERE J.ID IN (SELECT TOT_P.ID 
               FROM (SELECT P.ID, COUNT(*) 
                     FROM PARTIDOS P 
                     GROUP BY P.ID 
                     HAVING COUNT(*) > 50) TOT_P);
```

Comment: ESPERO ESTO VAYA AQUI: tengo una tabla de jugadores con todos sus datos incluye sueldo, rut, y otros campos ademas tengo la tabla partidos con su respectivo id por cada partido y el rut de cada jugador, entonces a cada jugador que ha jugado mas de 50 partidos  (puede ser 10 20 o cualquier otro numero) se le asigna el doble del sueldo en la tabla jugador (puede ser un porcentaje mas) pero depende de la cantidad de partidos jugados por eso contaba los id. de partidos cuando el rut es igual o puede ser otro campo. Espero este mas claro. y muchas gracias por responder

Comment: @EduardoOyarzun no, no era aquí, sino editando tu pregunta ;-)

Comment: Por favor, si la solución propuesta te ha valido marca la respuesta como válida.

Answer (score -1):

Si se trata solamente de multiplicar el sueldo por `2` cuando un jugador ha jugado mas de `50` partidos, entonces simplemente puedes evitar hacer el join moviendo la porción `partidos` fuera del `update` principal dentro de una subconsulta.

Te dejo 2 opciones, una de las cuales es similar a la que presenta @Miguel en su buena respuesta, pero simplificada:

Usando `IN`:

```
update jugadores
   set sueldo = sueldo * 2
 where rut in (select rut
                 from partidos
                group by rut
               having count(*) > 50)
```

O usando `EXISTS`:

```
update jugadores j
   set j.sueldo = j.sueldo * 2
 where exists (select null
                 from partidos p
                where p.rut = j.rut
               having count(*) > 50);
```

---

Ahora bien, si la idea es que vas a querer poner el sueldo al día dependiendo de la cantidad de partidos jugados, como aludes con los siguientes comentarios:

> Entonces, a cada jugador que ha jugado más de 50 partidos (***puede ser 10, 20 o cualquier otro número***) se le asigna el doble del sueldo en la tabla jugador (***puede ser un porcentaje más***), pero ***depende de la cantidad de partidos jugados***.

... entonces es necesario restructurar la consulta para que el `UPDATE` pueda tomar en cuenta la cantidad de partidos al asignar el nuevo sueldo.

Por poner un ejemplo, digamos que la lógica deseada es que, si el jugador ha jugado mas de 20 partidos, entonces recibe un aumento de 50%, pero si ha jugado mas de 50 partidos, entonces el sueldo se duplica.

Normalmente, este tipo de `UPDATE` se haría con un join, pero con Oracle, hacerlo de esta forma, aunque no imposible, es sumamente incómoda. Lo mejor en este caso es usar la sentencia `MERGE`:

```
merge into jugadores j
using (
  select rut,
         count(*) as cantidad
    from partidos
   group by rut
  having count(*) > 20
) p
on (p.rut = j.rut)
when matched then
  update set j.sueldo = case when p.cantidad > 50
                             then j.sueldo * 2
                             else j.sueldo * 1.5
                        end;
```

Si desearas usar un `UPDATE`, la consulta se escribiría de esta forma:

```
update (
  select j.rut,
         j.sueldo, 
         p.cantidad
    from jugadores j
    join (select rut, count(*) as cantidad
            from partidos
           group by rut
          having count(*) > 20) p
      on p.rut = j.rut
)
set sueldo = case when cantidad > 50
                  then sueldo * 2
                  else sueldo * 1.5
             end;
```

Pero, nuevamente, te recomiendo usar la sentencia `MERGE` ya que para lograr escribir una sentencia `UPDATE` que incluya joins y que corra con éxito, hay que tener mucho cuidado para no recibir el error siguiente:

> ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view

De hecho, creo que las reglas en cuanto a qué tipos de joins en los updates son permitidos han ido cambiando de versión en versión. De modo que es posible que el ejemplo de `UPDATE` que te puse no funcione según tu versión de Oracle.

Comment: muy agradecido y tu respuesta (usando in N°1) me sirvio exactamente para lo que queria. muchas gracias.---